# Disable checkout button

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am using drupal 7 with ubercart.  Since I do not currently have a method to accept credit cards, I am using paypal express.  The issue I am finding is that still in the cart view there is a checkout button and a paypal button.  If the user clicks the CHECKOUT button they are taken to the next page but can go no further since there are no Credit Card options currently enabled.

Is there a way to only show the PAYPAL button in the cart? If so where?  I am not sure which file I should be looking in for the cart form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to admin/store/settings/checkout and disable checkout.

[image]